# How to animate div size smoothly when its size changes due to children being added or removed (framer-motion)?

Tags: framer-motion

[image]

When the items removed by selecting the "all" option the div jumps in size, while i wish to slowly shrink so the animation feels smooth (at one point the separator line which is under the options cross over the "mindegy" option which i want to avoid).

This is some of the code, these are the children being added from a list it is contained within a div.

```
<AnimatePresence>
        {selectedOptions.map((option) => (
          <motion.div
            layout
            initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0}}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
            key={option.value}
            className="flex items-center  justify-center bg-slate-300 max-w-36 text-sm m-2  border border-slate-300 rounded-2xl">
            <div className="p-1 ml-2">{option.text}</div>
            <X
              onClick={() => updateSelection(option, false)}
              className="ml-1 mr-1 cursor-pointer hover:text-gray-500 text-zinc-600"
              size={16}
            />
          </motion.div>
        ))}
  </AnimatePresence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work but you can always slow down the animation by adding this:

```
exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0, transition:{duration:1} }}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried it but it does not help.